# imap_fetchbody and stripping below line

Tags: php

I have a script that checks emails and puts them in a database. This works fine when new emails are composed and sent. However, if I reply to an email the imap_fetchbody does not work and it is empty.

Where am I going wrong here?

```
/* get information specific to this email */
$overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
$structure = imap_fetchstructure($inbox,$email_number);
$message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,0);
$header = imap_headerinfo($inbox,$email_number);

//print_r($structure);

  //make sure emails are read or do nothing
if($overview[0]->seen = 'read'){  

//strip everything below line
$param="## In replies all text above this line is added to the ticket ##";
$strip_func = strpos($message, $param);
$message_new = substr($message,0,$strip_func );


  /* output the email body */
  $output.= '<div class="body">'.$message_new.'<br><br></div>';
```

If I output the $message instead of the $message_new so before I start stripping the text everything is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that line "In replies..." is not present in the message at all, `strpos` will return boolean `false`, which when coerced to an integer will be 0.

So when you ask for the substring from 0 to the position, you're asking for the substring from 0 to 0, and `$message_new` is empty.

Check if that line is present in the mail before you try to take a substring based on it.

```
$param="## In replies all text above this line is added to the ticket ##";
$strip_func = strpos($message, $param);
$message_new = ($strip_func === false) ? $message : substr($message,0,$strip_func);
```

Comment: That line is in the replies though. It has not been removed.

Comment: What's in the replies is not matching in `strpos` then. Start debugging. `var_dump $message` and `$strip_func`.

Comment: Nothing, if I reply from another email box it works. I made your changes and the body shows up now. It is just all jumbled up encoded text. That must be why the strip_func wasnt working it couldnt read the "in replies" since it is encoded. I guess my question is now, how do I decode all the text. I need to decode before the strip function though so it sees it.